# Delete all occurrences of specific values from list of lists python

Tags: python

As far as I can see this question (surprisingly?) has not been asked before - unless I am failing to spot an equivalent question due to lack of experience.  (Similar questions have
been asked about 1D lists)

I have a list_A that has int values in it. 
I want to delete all occurrences of all the values specified in List_A from my list_of_lists.  As a novice coder I can hack something together here myself using list comprehensions and for loops, but given what I have read about inefficiencies of deleting elements from within lists,  I am looking for advice from more experienced users about the fastest way to go about this.

```
list_of_lists= [
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9],
[0,2,4,5,6,7],
[0,1,6],
[0,4,9],
[0,1,3,5],
[0,1,4],
[0,1,2],
[1,8],
[0,7],
[0,3]
]
```

Further info

- I am not looking to eliminate duplicates (there is already a question on here about that). I am looking to eliminate all occurrences of selected values.
- list_A may typically have 200 values in it
- list_of_lists will have a similar (long tailed) distribution to that shown above but in the order of up to 10,000 rows by 10,000 columns
- Output can be a modified version of original list_of_lists or completely new list - whichever is quicker

Last but not least (thanks to RemcoGerlich for drawing attention to this) - I need to eliminate empty sublists from with the list of lists

Many thanks

Comment: If a sublist ends up empty, should it be removed or left behind as an empty list?

Comment: Should be removed - thanks I will edit OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using list comprehension should work as:

```
new_list = [[i for i in l if i not in list_A] for l in list_of_list]
```

After that, if you want to remove empty lists, you can make:

```
for i in new_list:
    if not i:
        new_list.remove(i)
```

of, as @ferhatelmas pointed in comments:

```
new_list = [i for i in new_list if i]
```

To avoid duplicates in `list_A` you can convert it to a set before with `list_A = set(list_A)`

Comment: It would be better to convert `list_A` to a set before doing this.

Comment: arshajii - excuse my ignorance, but could you elaborate on why?

Comment: In case you have duplicates, it would test just one with a set

Comment: @Fluff: because `i in items` is O(n) for a list but O(1) for a set (ie between 100 and 200 times faster for 200 items, depending on what hit ratio you expect to see).

Comment: @RubenBermudez `new_list = [i for i in new_list if i]` seems faster to me or at least with `if not i`.

Comment: @ferhatelmas are you talking about removing empty, don't you? Yes, it can be, I will update my answer with both options. Thx

Comment: @RubenBermudez Yes, I meant removing empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a function that just takes one list (or iterable) and a set, and returns a new list with the values from the set removed:

```
def list_without_values(L, values):
    return [l for l in L if l not in values]
```

Then I'd turn list_A into a set for fast checking, and loop over the original list:

```
set_A = set(list_A)
list_of_lists = [list_without_values(L, set_A) for L in list_of_lists]
```

Should be fast enough and readibility is what matters most.